# How to Identify link attribute range on moving cursor

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring

In UITextView some strings are linkAttributed, How to find the range of all only link attributed string. while editing textview? And Also  If user click on back(cross) for removing then can We remove complete link text.

Answer (score 0):

Enable Detection->Links options, the URL and also email will be detected and clickable

[image: here]